# Is it possible to limit permissions on the Trello board?

Tags: trello-cards, permissions

I want team members to upload documents to a card but not necessarily see the rest of the board. They should be able to track the card with the doc as it moves through various edits - but should only see their work.

Also, is it possible to limit access to lists on a board?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. Limitation is possible on board level only. You can expand the possibilities of this by using Trello business class: http://help.trello.com/article/732-adding-observers-to-boards